# Was the experiment with five monkeys, a ladder, a banana and a water spray conducted?

Tags: psychology, behavior, memory, morality

I've found the following picture online. It is about the moral/paradigm behind consistent behavior.

[image: Image shows text and cartoon illustrations. Transcribed below.]

[<sub>Click to enlarge.</sub>](http://i.snag.gy/kdu77.jpg)

The image text says

> - A group of scientists placed 5 monkeys in a cage and in the middle, a ladder with bananas on the top.
> - Every time a monkey went up the ladder, the scientists soaked the rest of the monkeys with cold water.
> - After a while, every time a monkey went up the ladder, the others beat up the one on the ladder.
> - After some time, no monkey dare[d] to go up the ladder regardless of the temptation.
> - Scientists then decided to substitute one of the monkeys. The 1<sup>st</sup> thing this new monkey did was to go up the ladder. Immediately the other monkeys beat him up.
>
>   - After several beatings, the new member learned not to climb the ladder even though he never knew why.
> - A 2<sup>nd</sup> monkey was substituted and the same occurred. The 1<sup>st</sup> monkey participated on [*sic*] the beating for [*sic*] the 2<sup>nd</sup> monkey. A 3<sup>rd</sup> monkey was changed and the same was repeated (beating). The 4<sup>th</sup> was substituted and the beating was repeated and finally the 5<sup>th</sup> monkey was replaced.
> - What was left was a group of 5 monkeys that even though never received a cold shower, continued to beat up any monkey who attempted to climb the ladder.
> - If it was possible to ask the monkeys why they would beat up all those who attempted to go up the ladder ... I bet you the answer would be ... **"I don't know — that's how things are done around here"** Does it sound familiar?
> - Don't miss the opportunity to share this with others as they might be asking themselves why we continue to do what we are doing if there is a different way out there.

This seems like an experiment, but now I'm wondering... **Was this experiment ever conducted? If not, was any similar experiment conducted that shows the same effect?**

Comment: Please link to the source of this picture.

Comment: One source for the picture (as slideshow): http://www.slideshare.net/shaldag/a-story-about-5-monkeys

Comment: @Chad: I had encountered this story, about two years ago, long before I saw this image on Facebook. If it's a made-up claim, it's a persistent one.

Comment: @Hendrik: Nice, how did you find that?

Comment: @Tom: Easy - at the moment it's result #10 for the google search in Flimzy's answer.

Comment: There were several positive negative reinforcement experiments performed but this sounds like an extrapolation of predicted results combined with humanized responses.  This story makes it sound like negative reinforcement alone can trigger this powerful anti social group behavior.  Its a myth

Comment: I never understood this as a serious claim, more as a gedankenexperiment. The outcome is untestable anyway – how would you ask the monkeys? – but very plausible given what we know about (human) nature.

Comment: You are probably anyway not allowed to do this kind of tests on monkeys any more. Nowadays you would need to use interns etc.

Comment: Reading the answers it seems there is no evidence that this experiment has ever been done.  I think it should be done.  If only I had 5 monkeys.

Comment: You need ten monkeys. . .

Comment: Actually they seem to me like pretty darn smart monkeys.  This effect is how humans avoid many dangers to astonishing levels of reliability, like traffic, poisonous berries, bad puns, and esoteric discussions.  Oh wait.

Comment: I got very excited when I noticed [this retelling](http://www.life-hack.co.uk/2014/03/the-experiment.html?m=1) attributed it to "The experiments of Harry Harlow and his associates at the Primate Laboratory of the University of Wisconsin are described in the textbook Principles of General Psychology (1980 John Wiley and Sons)" but searching through his work and the text book, I could not find any mention. Seems like a false attribution. Can anyone do better?

Comment: @Borror0 I've heard about this story so long ago I can't remember if it's 1 or 2 decades old - and I'd probably have said it the same back in Nov 2011 (because, coincidentally, I was [posting](http://cauecmrego.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/problemas-de-logica.html) about it back then). Just to say: _I'd bet this story is from past century._ Here's a not enough old link: http://www.wowzone.com/5monkeys.htm (google says it's from 2001)

Comment: http://www.wisdompills.com/2014/05/28/the-famous-social-experiment-5-monkeys-a-ladder/ attributes inspiration of it to Stephenson 1967 and Kohler from 1920s

Comment: What @BobStein-VisiBone said.  This story is told to show how people follow traditions mindlessly.  But the monkeys are helping each other avoid a bad outcome.  The consequences may be capricious (the researchers could stop spraying water), but the monkeys don't know that.  If the contraindicated activity were eating poisonous mushrooms, we wouldn't think the monkeys were clever for occasionally eating some to make sure they were still lethal.  Perhaps the real message of this thought experiment is that a tradition can have a good reason behind it, even if we've forgotten what that reason is?

Comment: Video of the experiment on humans here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEhSk71gUCQ

Comment: http://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/89q2/apes.513.html cites this story as having been told in the 1988 book *De banaan wordt bespreekbaar*, but as I don't have the book and don't know Dutch I can't verify that.

Comment: @Carmeister I do know Dutch and it looks legit to me; after further research I have seen various references, cites from other articles and books as well as a page scan. Given the political background and context, I'm starting to believe that this is somewhat a made up idea in order to convince people rather than an actual experiment to learn from ... but I'll continue to wait, every few months a new piece of the puzzle arrives in this question :-)

Comment: I don't have the rep required to answer an old question. But a very similar experiment was covered in hidden-camera style by the show _Brain Games_. There is a peer pressure social conformity episode. It looks like they reproduced the experiment by having everyone stand up in a waiting room when there was a beep. Not academic rigor, does satisfy your "similar experiment to same effect" request. It even gets to the point of the original population being removed but the behavior continuing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8BkzvP19v4

Comment: I have come across this in the past, but as the parable of the five monkeys, not a scientific experiment.  I regard it as an allegorical tale.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

The earliest mention I could find of this experiment was in the popular business/self-help book, [Competing for the future](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0875847161) by Gary Hamel and C. K. Prahalad (1996).  Here is the quote from the book:

> 4 monkeys in a room. In the center of the room is a tall pole with a bunch of bananas
>   suspended from the top. One of the four monkeys scampers up the pole and grabs the
>   bananas. Just as he does, he is hit with a torrent of cold water from an overhead shower.
>   He runs like hell back down the pole without the bananas. Eventually, the other three try
>   it with the same outcome. Finally, they just sit and don’t even try again. To hell with the
>   damn bananas. But then, they remove one of the four monkeys and replace him with a
>   new one. The new monkey enters the room, spots the bananas and decides to go for it.
>   Just as he is about to scamper up the pole, the other three reach out and drag him back
>   down. After a while, he gets the message. There is something wrong, bad or evil that
>   happens if you go after those bananas. So, they kept replacing an existing monkey with a
>   new one and each time, none of the new monkeys ever made it to the top. They each got
>   the same message. Don’t climb that pole. None of them knew exactly why they
>   shouldn’t climb the pole, they just knew not to. They all respected the well established
>   precedent. EVEN AFTER THE SHOWER WAS REMOVED! ([Source](http://www.altfeldinc.com/pdfs/Competing%20for%20the%20Future.pdf))

The authors did not provide a source for this claim.  This story was later repeated in [various](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0767911903) [other](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785288570) popular business/self-help books.

Every source online I could find erroneously attributed the experiment to one of the above authors.  No one, *anywhere*, seems to have a reference to the actual experiment.

---

C. K. Prahalad is deceased, but Gary Hamel is still alive.  I tried contacting him several times, but unfortunately both he and his secretary were very evasive.  The best I could get was

> Our apologies, but Professor Hamel does not have the original source information at hand in terms of your request.

Given that there seems to be no evidence **anywhere** of this experiment ever actually taking place, that all trails of references eventually lead to the claim in this book, and that this is the earliest available mention of the experiment, until further evidence becomes available the most reasonable conclusion is that **C. K. Prahalad or Gary Hamel made up the experiment for their book.**

---

Even if the above authors were not the creators of the myth, there is still reason to believe that, as @Chad puts it (comments above), this claim is an *"extrapolation of predicted results combined with humanized responses."*

[Here](http://www.fastcompany.com/magazine/10/cdu10.html) is a quote from an *"anthropology professor who's worked with hundreds of monkeys over the last 30 years."*  When asked what he thought of the experiment, he responded succinctly with:

> If you have bananas on a pole, you'll lose your bananas.

Comment: That last quote is interesting, I'm still wondering what Gary Hamel has to say about that.

Comment: @Tom: see edit.  I've given up trying to contact him.  Perhaps if [more people ask](http://www.garyhamel.com/contact.html), we can get a better response.

Comment: Thank you for leaving a comment, it's interesting that it could be made up. I might look into contacting him.

Comment: Followup question: if 4 more people replied that it's not a real experiment, would the next person reply without even bothering to do the research?

Comment: What do monkeys have to do with this? I thought this was about chimps?

Comment: The **human version** of this experiment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asch_conformity_experiments

Comment: It's not a real experiment. Source: everyone else told me it wasn't real when I got here.

Comment: @JeffSahol Don't need 4 more replies. You have 274 upvotes.

Comment: The earth was flat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_men_make_a_tiger

Comment: @Pacerier, there are 4 lights. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moX3z2RJAV8

Comment: In India, bullshitting is a pass time of the privileged. Making shitup about poor & then codifying that shit in some alleged "holy books" to justify an oppressive caste system has been done for millennia. As a follow Indian, I would not be surprised if this fiction originated from the mind of C. K. Prahalad

Answer (score 219):

**TL;DR:** It sounds like a similar monkey experiment did take place, and the results were similar to that presented in the picture, but if this is the same experiment, most of the details are wrong.

The [first google result](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Did_the_monkey_banana_and_water_spray_experiment_ever_take_place) for [monkeys ladder experiment](http://www.google.com.mx/#hl=en&source=hp&q=monkeys+ladder+experiment) contains to the following information:

> Stephenson (1967) trained adult male and female rhesus monkeys to avoid manipulating an object and then placed individual naïve animals in a cage with a trained individual of the same age and sex and the object in question. In one case, a trained male actually pulled his naïve partner away from the previously punished manipulandum during their period of interaction, whereas the other two trained males exhibited what were described as "threat facial expressions while in a fear posture" when a naïve animal approached the manipulandum. When placed alone in the cage with the novel object, naïve males that had been paired with trained males showed greatly reduced manipulation of the training object in comparison with controls. Unfortunately, training and testing were not carried out using a discrimination procedure so the nature of the transmitted information cannot be determined, but the data are of considerable interest.

Sources: 
Stephenson, G. R. (1967). Cultural acquisition of a specific learned response among rhesus monkeys. In: Starek, D., Schneider, R., and Kuhn, H. J. (eds.), Progress in Primatology, Stuttgart: Fischer, pp. 279-288.

Mentioned in: Galef, B. G., Jr. (1976). Social Transmission of Acquired Behavior: A Discussion of Tradition and Social Learning in Vertebrates. In: Rosenblatt, J.S., Hinde, R.A., Shaw, E. and Beer, C. (eds.), Advances in the study of behavior, Vol. 6, New York: Academic Press, pp. 87-88.

The above quote is found on page 88 of [the 1976 document quoted above](http://books.google.co.za/books?id=x_hfmoOaHpoC&lpg=PA77&ots=IqFtSYj5di&dq=Social%20Transmission%20of%20Acquired%20Behavior%3A%20A%20Discussion%20of%20Tradition%20and%20Social%20Learning&lr&pg=PA88#v=onepage).

It is possible the claim is referring to this experiment, with diverging details, or that another experiment took place that was closer to the details in the claim.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, after reading the paper  link bellow, it does look like the beginning of the described experiment; learning passed on. It does fail to join all subjects that haven't interacted with the object and have them pass their knowledge to their fellow kin. I would say the folloing 'anecdote' uses the basis for this experiment and greatly builds upon it. The answer to the OP would be NO, it hasn't. http://www.scribd.com/doc/73492989/Stephenson-1966-Cultural-Acquisition-of-a-Specific-Learned-Response-Among-Rhesus-Monkeys

Comment: Stephenson's paper: https://erikbuys.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/cultural-acquisition-of-a-specific-learned-response-among-rhesus-monkeys-gordon-r-stephenson.pdf.