# A source for the monkey ladder water experiment?

Tags: psychology, behavior, learning

[This post](https://niume.com/pages/post/?postID=273774) claims that the experiment was described "in the textbook Principles of General Psychology (1980 John Wiley and Sons)" ([Google](https://books.google.com/books?id=fcC4AAAACAAJ&dq=978-0471044697&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWjq_YoM3SAhUHbiYKHXaKDL8Q6AEIIzAB),[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471044695))

Can someone with access to the book confirm whether or not that is the case, and if so whether a source is cited?

(This claim about the textbook is not evaluated in [this related question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6828); a "yes" to this question does imply a "yes" to that question, but not vice-versa.)

> A group of scientists placed 5 monkeys in a cage and in the middle a ladder with bananas on top...
>
> The experiments of Harry Harlow and his associates at the Primate Laboratory of the University of Wisconsin are described in the textbook Principles of General Psychology (1980 John Wiley and Sons)
>
> [image: Summary of experiment as text in an image]

Comment: Answers to this related question indicate a lack of sourcing in other mentions, and a possible connection to a rather different experiment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/was-the-experiment-with-five-monkeys-a-ladder-a-banana-and-a-water-spray-condu

Comment: This whole question appears like it should be a comment on the other question (or answer)

Comment: I thought about putting it there but it didn't seem to fit: it's obviously not an answer; as a comment on an answer it's like asking someone who already put work into one answer to do more work to find another; as a comment on the question it seems like a lazy way to avoid asking a question.  so I asked a question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate; nothing in that question or its answers addresses whether this particular textbook has a source for that experiment.

Comment: I would agree that it's not a duplicate, but it also doesn't seem to be notable.  Is it a widely held belief that that textbook describes the experiment?  This seems particularly trivial.  If the experiment existed but was not in the book, then what?  If the experiment did not exist but was in the book, then what?  This seems to reflect more on one obscure textbook than anything publicly believed.  I.e. the question of the existence of the experiment is notable but its presence in the textbook would not be.

Comment: If the textbook has a reference, then that is the answer to the other question.  This is a useful hint to someone trying to answer the other question.